# How to Change $request_uri to first original, Nginx

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, uri, request-uri

Example:

-Step 1. Example Client request: `http://domain/123` => (so now in Nginx: $request_uri original == /123)

-Step 2. If i config nginx redirect or something like that `http://domain/123` to `http://domain/456` => ($request_uri in Nginx will change: `$request_uri  == /456`)

I want when i get $request_uri right now it will be = /123, how i can do that? Thanks

Something like this:

```
proxy_set_header Original-uri $request_uri ;
```

How to keep variable of first request_uri?

Comment: `If i config nginx redirect` — if that means 301/302 redirect, then there is no *sane* way to keep orginal url.

Comment: Ok,  there is no way to keep orginal url for $request_uri. So, i just want get variable of first request uri (=/123), can i do that?

Comment: You could pass it as query argument. But why do you need redirect in first place?

Comment: Thanks for your advise, this is my problem "github.com/kyprizel/testcookie-recaptcha-processor/issues/1" $testcookie_nexturl does not work when i call it in location = /captcha {..proxy_set_header Testcookie-Nexturl $testcookie_nexturl;.} => so i try replace it by $request_uri but no luck, because request_uri right now is =/captcha

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

`proxy_set_header Original-uri $request_uri;` change to

```
proxy_set_header Original-uri  $http_referer;
```

Because request uri =/123 is **referer** of request uri =/456